# Trait or state? What statistic analysis should I use when expecting no effect?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, anova, psychology

I want to test whether a certain questionnaire (with 52 items on 6 point Likert scale) measures a trait (stable characteristic) or state (experience that is dependent on time and context).

To test this, I will let my participants (N=40) fill out this questionnaire in two different contexts (neutral vs. not neutral). 
My hypothesis is that this questionnaire measures a trait - so it is expected that context does NOT (significantly) influence the score on this questionnaire.

What statistical analysis should I use? Anova (repeated measures analysis) is probably not sufficient when expecting no effect... And with this little amount of available participants (40) it would also not be reasonable to use a Latent trait-state-(occasion) model - to test how much variance is due to context and person variables -, or would it?

Who can help me?

Kind regards,

Eva

ps. the neutral vs. non-neutral do differ in experimental set-up..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have only 2 groups, neutral and non neutral. Thus, all you need are the tools for 2 group comparisons, paired t-test instead of repeated measures anova, Wilcoxon sum rank instead of Kruskal-Wallis (if you want to work with the non paired data), and so on.

Now, if you want to "prove" that the questionnaire measure a trait, and thus that the neutral and non-neutral have no difference, what you need is an equivalence test - the tag [equivalence] is your friend here.